# Two onmouseout events doing the same action on their respective elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have a script which validates the inputs entered upon an `onmouseout` event. Firstly when the user move the cursor away from the first input, the validation occurs and the error message is shown.  I want to do the same process with the second input, that is, an error message is shown when the cursor is moved away from the second input.  Below is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $('document').ready(function () {
         $('#Make').on('mouseout', function () {
             $("#carform").validate({
                 rules: {
                     Make: {
                         required: true
                     }
                 },
                 messages: {
                     Make: {
                         required: "Please enter a make"
                     }
                 },
                 submitHandler: function (form) {
                     form.submit();
                 }
             });
             if ($("#carform").valid()) {
                 //Do some code
             }
         });
         $('#Model').on('mouseout', function () {
             $("#carform").validate({
                 rules: {
                     Model: {
                         required: true
                     }
                 },
                 messages: {
                     Model: {
                         required: "Please enter a model"
                     }
                 },
                 submitHandler: function (form) {
                     form.submit();
                 }
             });
             if ($("#carform").valid()) {
                 //Do some code
             }
         });
     });

</script>
```

My view:

```
<div>
    <form id="carform" method="post">
        <p>
            @Html.LabelFor(l=>l.Make)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(l => l.Make)
        </p>
        <p>
            @Html.LabelFor(l=>l.Model)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(l => l.Model)
        </p>
        <p>
            <input id="createCar" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
        </p>
    </form>

</div>
```

When I move my cursor away from the input Make, the error message is seen.  But when I do the same with the second input Model, no error message is seen. Any idea where I am doing it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to initialize it once.. Not on each `input blur` and you have option in `jquery validation` which validates on `blur` which is as below:

[**`onfocusout`**](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#onfocusout)

> **Type:** Boolean or Function()
>
> Validate elements (except checkboxes/radio buttons) on blur. If
>   nothing is entered, all rules are skipped, except when the field was
>   already marked as invalid.
>
> *Set to a Function to decide for yourself when to run validation.*
>
> **A `boolean` true is not a valid value.**
>
> Example: Disables `onblur` validation.

```
$(".selector").validate({
  onfocusout: false //Do not use false instead use a callback function
});
```

The callback gets passed two arguments:

> element

**Type: Element The element currently being validated, as a DOMElement.**

> event

**Type: Event The event object for this focusout event.**

So you can make use of callback function as below in your case:

```
$('document').ready(function () {
    $("#carform").validate({
          onfocusout: function(element) {
               this.element(element);
          },
          rules: {
                 Make: {
                       required: true
                 },
                 Model: {
                     required: true //keep both the required here
                 }
          },
          messages: {
                 Make: {
                       required: "Please enter a make"
                 },
                 Model: {
                       required: "Please enter a model" //keep both the messages here
                 }
          },
          submitHandler: function (form) {
                 if ($(form).valid()) { //check for valid form here
                    form.submit()//submit here
                 }
          }
    });

   $('#Make,#Model').on('blur', function() {
        $("#carform").validate().element( this );
   });
});
```

Comment: I replaced the whole javascript with your code, but I get nothing now.  I have this error on my console though: 'Uncaught TypeError: i.settings[s].call is not a function'. Do I need to add anything else?

Comment: Check the updated answer please.. Sorry for wrong interpretation.. @tabby

Comment: Great.. Happy Coding.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Simple, define a same class for both inputs say class `foo`

and check `mouseout` event with class as an identifier like:

```
$('.foo').on('mouseout', function () {
 // your code here
});
```